# Append Div as child on button

Tags: javascript, accordion

```
<select name="pList" id="pList" style="display: none">
  <option value="">--ProductA--</option>
  <option value="productA">ProdA</option>
  <option value="productA">ProdA</option>
  <option value="productA">ProdA</option>
  <option value="">--ProductB--</option>
  <option value="productB">ProdB</option>
  <option value="productB">ProdB</option>
  <option value="">--ProducstC--</option>
  <option value="productC">ProdC</option>
  <option value="productC">ProdC</option>
  <option value="productC">ProdC</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to transform the above select values into an accordion, I was able to successfully create new button element with the correct values for the heading, but when I try to append each select  values as child, inside the button(should work as accordion), is not working correctly, its just adds values to the heading, please see: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bernlt/txgnk89w/5/

```
   var element = document.getElementById('pList');
   var children = element.children;
   var filtered = [];
   var filterItens = [];
  // Create Headings for the Button e.g: --ProductA--/--ProductB--/--ProductC--
   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (children[i].textContent.startsWith('--')) {
          filtered.push(children[i].textContent); //Heading labels
        }else{
        // separate array listing all products
          filterItens.push(children[i].textContent);  
        }
      }
      var prods= filtered.toString().split(',');
      var itens = filterItens.toString().split(',');

   for (var i in prods) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('button');   
    newElement.className = "accordion";
    newElement.innerHTML = prods[i];
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {  // get arraylist values
    if (children[i].value=="productA"){ 
      var foo = document.getElementById("--ProductA--");
      var newElement = document.createElement('div');
      newElement.id = children[i].value; 
      newElement.className = "productA";
      newElement.innerHTML = children[i].text;
      foo.appendChild(newElement);
    } 
    if (children[i].value=="productB"){
      var foo = document.getElementById("--ProductB--");
      var newElement = document.createElement('div');
      newElement.id = children[i].value; 
      newElement.className = "productB";
      newElement.innerHTML = children[i].text;
      foo.appendChild(newElement);
    }
    if (children[i].value=="productC"){
      var foo = document.getElementById("--ProducstC--");
      var newElement = document.createElement('div');
      newElement.id = children[i].value; 
      newElement.className = "productC";
      newElement.innerHTML = children[i].text;
      foo.appendChild(newElement);
    }
}
```

I'm open to any other suggestions, as this is aprt of my learning path, basically I'm trying to create accordion using select, so any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `max-height: 0;` when you aren't hovering over the button. When you hover, set the `max-height` to an arbitrary number, I used `200px` so you get the accordion effect.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('pList');
   var children = element.children;
   var filtered = [];
   var filterItens = [];
   // Create Headings for the Button e.g: --ProductA--/--ProductB--/--ProductC--
   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
     if (children[i].textContent.startsWith('--')) {
       filtered.push(children[i].textContent); //Heading labels
     } else {
       filterItens.push(children[i].textContent); // separate array listing all products
     }
   }
   var prods = filtered.toString().split(',');
   var itens = filterItens.toString().split(',');

   for (var i in prods) {
     var newElement = document.createElement('button'); //button
     newElement.id = prods[i];
     newElement.className = "accordion";
     newElement.innerHTML = prods[i];
     document.body.appendChild(newElement);
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // get arraylist values
     if (children[i].value == "productA") {
       var foo = document.getElementById("--ProductA--");
       var newElement = document.createElement('div');
       newElement.id = children[i].value;
       newElement.className = "productA";
       newElement.innerHTML = children[i].text;
       foo.appendChild(newElement);
     }
     if (children[i].value == "productB") {
       var foo = document.getElementById("--ProductB--");
       var newElement = document.createElement('div');
       newElement.id = children[i].value;
       newElement.className = "productB";
       newElement.innerHTML = children[i].text;
       foo.appendChild(newElement);
     }
     if (children[i].value == "productC") {
       var foo = document.getElementById("--ProducstC--");
       var newElement = document.createElement('div');
       newElement.id = children[i].value;
       newElement.className = "productC";
       newElement.innerHTML = children[i].text;
       foo.appendChild(newElement);
     }
   }
```

```css
button.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  max-height: 40px; /* Added */
  overflow: hidden; /* Added */
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  max-height: 200px; /* Added */
}

button.accordion:after {
  position: absolute; /* Added */
  top: 10px; /* Added */
  right: 10px; /* Added */
  /* float: right; Remove */
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

div.Hardware {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<select name="pList" id="pList" style="display: none">
  <option value="">--ProductA--</option>
  <option value="productA">ProdA</option>
  <option value="productA">ProdA</option>
  <option value="productA">ProdA</option>
  <option value="">--ProductB--</option>
  <option value="productB">ProdB</option>
  <option value="productB">ProdB</option>
  <option value="">--ProducstC--</option>
  <option value="productC">ProdC</option>
  <option value="productC">ProdC</option>
  <option value="productC">ProdC</option>
</select>
```

You may need to tweak the initial `max-height: 40px;` that I set to your liking as well as the `:hover` state's `max-height`.

If you want an exact `max-height` you can handle the hover with Javascript. Count the children of the hovered element, add their outer heights together, and add style attribute via JS to the parent and remove it on blur.

Also, rather than using float for the `+` icon switch to an absolute position for this instance. Using float here, with `max-width` causes the `+` icon to be hidden when not hovered.